# react-bootstrap v5.2 package, dropdown component is not working

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/) package component, I copied exactly same component mentioned in the documentation [here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/). The dropdown style is coming fine but the dropdown is not opening.
Here is the code:-

```
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
export default function Menu(){
    return(
          <>
            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Drop">
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">Action</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
          </>
    )
}
```

While clicking on the Drop button, dropdown items are not opening

Comment: Have you imported the [stylesheets](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets)?

Comment: everything is imported, the button is styled in bootstrap already but when Im clicking the dropdown it won't open

Comment: I'm having a hard time recreating your issue, could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) for the problem